# Passing an attribute from a parent to a child class

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

I am trying to create a child class called `Beams` which is an extension of the `Elements` class. The latter computes the length of the element and stores it as an attribute of the `Elements` class. I would like to somehow pass the `length` to the child class. What is the right way to do it?

Please note: my code does not instantiate the `Elements` class directly. Rather its attributes are used in the instances of the `Beam` class through inheritance.

```
class Elements:

    def __init__(self,number,start_node,end_node,e_modulus,cs_area):

        self.number = number
        self.start_node = start_node
        self.end_node = end_node
        self.e_modulus = e_modulus

        d_x = end_node.x_glob - start_node.x_glob
        d_y = end_node.y_glob - start_node.y_glob

        self.length = mt.sqrt(d_x**2 + d_y**2)
        self.alpha = mt.atan2(d_y, d_x)

        r1 = mt.cos(self.alpha)
        r2 = mt.sin(self.alpha)

        self.rot_matrix = np.array([[r1,  r2, 0, 0,   0,  0],
                                   [-r2, r1, 0, 0,   0,  0],
                                   [0,   0,  1, 0,   0,  0],
                                   [0,   0,  0, r1,  r2, 0],
                                   [0,   0,  0, -r2, r1, 0],
                                   [0,   0,  0, 0,   0,  1]])


class Beam(Elements):

    def __init__(self,number,start_node,end_node,e_modulus,cs_area,second_mom_of_area):
        super().__init__(number,start_node,end_node,e_modulus,cs_area)
        self.second_mom_of_area = second_mom_of_area


        k1 = (e_modulus*cs_area)/length
        k2 = (12*e_modulus*second_mom_of_area)/(length**3)
        k3 = (6*e_modulus*second_mom_of_area)/(length**2)
        k4 = (4*e_modulus*second_mom_of_area)/(length)
        k5 = (2*e_modulus*second_mom_of_area)/(length)

        self.loc_stiff_matrix = np.array([[ k1,   0,   0, -k1,   0,   0],
                                         [  0,  k2,  k3,   0, -k2, -k3],
                                         [  0,  k3,  k4,   0, -k3,  k5],
                                         [-k1,   0,   0,  k1,   0,   0],
                                         [  0, -k2, -k3,   0,  k2,   0],
                                         [  0,  k3,  k5,   0, -k3,  k4]])
```

Comment: Length is a member. You can do `self.length` in the child class.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow missed that when reading about inheritance and thought one should also pass the attributes like one does when using the super()__init__ for the constructor. Now I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you define in your parent class is inherited by the child and, unless explicitly modified in the body of the child, they are directly accessible as attributes.

In your case:

```py
beam = Beam(**kwargs)

print(beam.length)
# or
print(getattr(beam, "length"))
```

should work.